# How to vertically center an HR element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

How do I vertically center an `hr` element?

I've tried to place the element in some `div` elements...

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell"><hr /></div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">Some text Here!</div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell"><hr /></div>
</div>
```

I've left out that I am using bootstrap and have these three `div` elements with the `class` of table in the same row using the col-size-number format.

---

So I'm looking for inline HR element Some Text inline HR element

--------------SOME TEXT--------------

Thank you again css guru masters!

Comment: why do you want a horizontal rule in your table cell with no content? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Consider using border instead. `hr` is not for visual styling, and is harder to work with.

Comment: For those editing my question, do not edit the line "So I'm looking for inline HR element Some Text inline HR element" your edits do not reflect what was being asked.

Comment: The question asked says how to vertically center an HR element, but this is how to center text within a horizontal HR element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone who's stumbled upon this in the future, I have updated the answer to what I feel is a more modern, efficient approach using `Flexbox`

HTML:

```
<div class="title">
  <hr />
  <h3>Some text</h3>
  <hr />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
hr {
  flex:1;
}
h3 {
   padding:0px 48px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvajk4xd/1/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i guess i was unclear, i'll update my question as well, I would like the HR tags to be at the sides of the text, vertically in the middle

Comment: Hey i just got it working rearranging your code http://jsfiddle.net/Rf467/1/   thanks a bunch!

Comment: Jemiloii found the answer rearranging the code, but the code in this post is not the answer, check Jacquen post or jemiloii comment link to get a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

For a simple, generic way to vertically center an `hr` element:

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <hr />
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.container hr {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `hr` element needs a `width` given to it (or `flex-grow`), otherwise it will be only a dot in the center of the container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.container hr {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This answers the short form of the question although it appears they were meaning to ask something else.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following solution in my css, margin the element to the center on every device
**CSS**:
    `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: That achieves horizontal centering, not vertical.